# Netezza "not exists" within a CASE statement

Tags: subquery, case, exists, netezza

I have a multi-layered CASE statement, and one of the conditions needs to reference a table via a "not exists".  I keep getting the error about 'correlated subqueries not allowed".  How can I reference a table along with a condition inside a CASE statement? Below is a portion of my code:

```
WHEN ......  previous condition  

WHEN ( CCOB_CLIENT_LOB_ID = 2  AND OI_CARRIER_LOB_ID IN (1,2,12,13) ) 
         and not exists ( select S.STATE  
                          FROM CCOB_PACIFICSOURCE.V_SELFPAY_COB_STATES  S
                          WHERE S.STATE = SELFPAY_COB_STATE )  then 'NONE'

WHEN ....  subsequent condition
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you cann’t.
The longer answer is that you have to rewrite the query to outer join the table you give the alias S.
Then it’s quite possible to test for NULL.
Watch out for dublicates on the S.state column though :)